# Angular material select appears incorrectly

Tags: angular-material

I am trying to use the select component from angular material but it appears incorrectly:

[image]

I have copied and pasted the code from the angular material site:

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Has backdrop</mat-label>
        <mat-select #hasBackdrop>
          <mat-option>Unset</mat-option>
          <mat-option [value]="true">True</mat-option>
          <mat-option [value]="false">False</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RoutesRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
  ],
})
```

I havent added any other css rules.

If anyone can help i would appreciate it!

Comment: Hi Billy, did you come up with a solution for this problem? Because although the Angular Material website shows a correct select with the items below the label, in my own project I get the same behavior as you have described...

Comment: Ηello, no i havent yet. I believe this i a bug in the angular material. Every component i used had the same behaviour. Random styles were applied for no reason. And these styles come from javascript not from any css file..

Comment: Hi, I got it fixed by using the latest Angular Material version: 15.1.0